# How to add the AdSense to my apps

Tags: android, adsense

Few days ago, I enter my Admob account. It has a information about Google will no longer to support Admob on 01/05. And than it requests to create a AdSense account. Now I created AdSense account, But I don't know how to add the AdSense in my apps. 
  Who can teach me how to do it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Go to adsense site where you can got sample code.

Answer (score 2):

> The message you mentioned is no longer displayed on the Admob signup
>   or after login.

AdMob requires you to have a valid AdSense account and AdWords account. If you don't have one or both of these accounts, Google will help you create them during the sign-up process and connect them to your Google Account.

You can signup to Admob in the [5 Step Signup process here](https://apps.admob.com/signup/). Once signed up you will be redirected to the [admob home page](https://apps.admob.com/#home). You can either [Monetize](https://apps.admob.com/#monetize), [Promote](https://apps.admob.com/#promote) and [Analyze](https://apps.admob.com/#analyze) the new app.